# Thymeleaf Literal being processed as a fragment reference

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to setup a page using fragments, and am having trouble with literals.

**index.html template**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="~{main_components::common_header('Home Page',_)}">
</head>
<body>
<p>Get your greeting <a href="/greeting">here</a></p>

<div th:insert="~{main_components::footer}"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**main_components template:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head th:fragment="common_header(title,links)" >

    <title th:replace="${title}">The awesome application</title>

    <!-- Common styles and scripts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" th:href="@{/css/awesomeapp.css}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" th:href="@{/images/favicon.ico}">
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/sh/scripts/codebase.js}"></script>

    <!--/* Per-page placeholder for additional links */-->
    <th:block th:replace="${links}"/>

</head>

<body>

<div th:fragment="footer">
    &copy; 2019 EBP :)
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

The issue here is that the literal `'Home Page'` seems to be treated as a reference to another fragment, resulting in the following error when trying to access `index`:

`org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [Home Page], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template: "main_components" - line 7, col 12)`

I am using a very basic setup at the moment based on [This Spring MVC Tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/). What do I need to do to get literals passed properly as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

`th:replace` is meant to replace the whole tag, which would be searching for something to replace it with. I switched it to use `th:text`, which had the desired affect.